# How can I prevent the Internet Explorer Info Bar from appearing when a user downloads a file?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Currently to have to user download a file I have the following javascript.

```
document.location.href = 'Filesave.ashx?filename=file.zip';
```

However this results in the 'To help product your security..' info bar to show up in IE and once the user refreshes the page they are unable to go to their download.

I saw somewhere that you can set the source of a hidden iframe to the file and this would not cause the security issue in IE. I have tried this but am unable to get it working, the info bar still appears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a scriptable object (thankfully). If it were, everyone serving up malware would get rid of it too.